# How to select a web element by text with Selenium WebDriver, Java

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I need to find the following element on the web page

```
<div class="b-datalist__item__addr">noreply@somedomain.com</div>
```

I'm coding with Java for Selenium WebDriver.
Need the exact CSS selector for this element to use it with `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(the-selector).click` command.
`div[class='b-datalist__item__addr']`  selector is not good enough since I must search according to `noreply@somedomain.com` text that is not a link so I can't use `findElement(By.linkText())` command.

Comment: Dear @Prophet can you look at my question? your vast knowledge can solve my issue 
[issue ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74528243/using-javascript-in-selenium-command-is-revoked-by-windows-security-settings ) better

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Css does not allow you do text based search. *xpath* is the only option there.

```
//div[contains(text(),'noreply@somedomain.com')]
```

Comment: is there a way to add the classname or any additional parameter to the xpath selector above?

Comment: @Eliyahu Yes. you can easily add `//div[contains(text(),'noreply@somedomain.com')][@class='classname']`. Using `@` since classname is an attribute

Answer (score 3):

[`contains(node, substring)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) might solve the problem, but note that if there are several elements with similar text contents, e.g.

- noreply@somedomain.com
- office.noreply@somedomain.com
- home.noreply@somedomain.com

Predicate `[contains(text(),'noreply@somedomain.com')]` will match all of them

In this case it's better to use [`starts-with(node, substring)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with):

```
//div[starts-with(text(),'noreply@somedomain.com')]
```

or fetch required element by exact text content:

```
//div[text()='noreply@somedomain.com']
```