# How do I properly identify a selector by its text in css instead of xpath

Tags: css, selenium, capybara

when I set up some simple html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label>Name:</label><input type="text"></form><br/>
      <label>Phone:</label><input type="text">
    </form>
    <div>happy</div>
    <div>angry</div> 
    <div>sad</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to specify a div by its text but wasn't able to

```
 div[@text='happy']              #nope
 html body div[@text='angry']    #nope
 html body div:contains('angry') #nope
 html body div[text='angry']     #nope
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find an element that contains specific text in Selenium Webdriver (Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323403/how-do-i-find-an-element-that-contains-specific-text-in-selenium-webdriver-pyth)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648554/how-to-select-a-web-element-by-text-with-selenium-webdriver-java

Comment: Some versions of Selenium do support :contains(), but I assume you're using Selenium WebDriver, which does not, because :contains() is no longer in the standard.

Comment: So looking at the links,  I'm getting that specifing by text, which is a great way to make the selector references robust, is not supported in anyway via css.  You'd use xpath which can employ ```div[contains(text(),'angry')]```

Comment: @TangibleDream: Yes - you'll need XPath for this.

Comment: Side question...  Top 5 reasons to use :css over :xpath?

Comment: The only reason to use CSS over XPath is that CSS is much simpler for a majority of use cases. XPath doesn't have a dedicated function for matching class names for example - CSS has class selectors. XPath 2.0 does have id(), but not all browsers implement XPath 2.0 - CSS has the ID selector. On the other hand if you're coming from an XML/XPath background, using XPath is a no-brainer, though you'd still have to cope with the limitations that arise from browsers not implementing XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS doesn't have a way to match on text content of elements, but Capybaras find provides a `text` option to filter by the text content.  It takes a string or a regex

```
angry_div = find(:css, 'div', text: 'angry') # The :css can be omitted if Capybara.default_selector = :css (which it is by default)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

```css
 div[type='happy']{
   background-color:red;
 }
```

```html
<form>
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text"></form><br/>
<label>Phone:</label><input type="text">
</form>
<div type="happy">happy</div>
<div>angry</div>
<div>sad</div>
```

Comment: nice idea, however, I am not in control of how the actual html is written. So I can't punt to searching by type.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this answer 1) Polluting the markup with invalid attributes 2) The markup is probably not within their control in the first place 3) The question is not about CSS